# Are there statements which can be proven by contradiction but not constructively?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, constructive-mathematics

Brouwer and the intuitionist mathematicians denied that a proof by contradiction was valid. Is it demonstrable that certain proofs/theorems then become inaccessible, i.e. without using proof by contradiction it is impossible to show them.

For instance, when I proved that the open cover of a compact set could be reduced to a finite cover, my intuition was that a proof by contradiction was required.

Comment: Bear in mind intuitionism isn't synonymous with constructivism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean intuitionistic logic, i.e. logic without LEM, then yes, a lot actually.

For example, Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem, which state that if you have 2 sets $A,B$ with injective from $A$ to $B$ and injective from $B$ to $A$, then there exists bijective from $A$ to $B$.

Apparently CBS is equivalent to LEM under IZF(ZF axioms in intuitionistic logic).

But there are much more! For example, it is consistent that there is injective function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb N$. Or that there is bijection from $2^{2^{\Bbb N}}$ to $\Bbb N$. Or even that all real functions are continuous!

Comment: thank you! i proved cantor-bernstein as a fun exercise over the summer and that's actually quite surprising, as the proof 'felt' constructive in nature.

Comment: do you know if there are any axioms sets where it doesn't make a difference? e.g. if we restricted ourselves to integer mathematics based of the peano axioms?

Comment: @Ethan in ZFC we have that, because Axiom of choice implies LEM